# Autofocus In Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal scroll-able div with list items.which looks like below. I want the list to be autofocused when user clicks on any list items. Presently, the list item sits at its position. Is there any way in Javascript or Jquery to autofocus the list item ?

Following are the CSS which I used for making this horizontal scroll div

on ul

```
white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-x: auto;
```

on li

```
display: inline-block !important;
    float: none;
```

[image: Horizontal List]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, $(YourElement).trigger("focus").

Answer (score 0):

Or even most easy, $(YourElement).click(); 
Dont forget to use the :active pseudo class in your css code for 'YourElement'.